# Jquery -trigger class only where it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having multiple divs with same the same class.

```
<div class="myClass" id="1">content1</div>
<div class="myClass" id="2">content2</div>
<div class="myClass" id="3">content3</div>
```

When I click the class, I'm having a function that triggers:

```
$('.myClass').click(function () {
            $('#1').note({ focus: true });
        });
```

the problem is: How can I trigger the class only where it's clicked?
If I'm using the solution above, `<div class="myClass" id="1">content1</div>` triggers when I click on any of the divs with `class="myClass"`

And If I'm using this below, then I need a function for each div:

```
$('#1').click(function () {
            $('#1').note({ focus: true });
        });
```

//Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `this` keyword

```
$('.myClass').click(function () {
            $(this).note({ focus: true });
        });
```